# 1993 Mitsubishi Colt sometimes refuses to start

Tags: engine, electrical, mitsubishi, intermittent-problems, colt

We have a 1993 Mk4 Colt 1.6 Auto.

The car runs absolutely fine but once in a while the engine refuses to start.

The starter and battery are fine; the fuel filter and all other servicables were recently replaced.

After a few days ,the mechanic (!) turned up to recover the car... and it fired right up. A few days later the same scenario occurred. The mechanic performed some diagnostics and was not very specific: weak spark signal and also a very quiet fuel pump.

My own little research so far has shown that it is not known to repair workshops that distributors were ever replaced..

Any help is very welcome; we are at our wit's end!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please review [My vehicle refuses to start. What information should I provide?](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1518/675). When it doesn't start, is the engine hot/warm?

Comment: Does it sputter at all, or just turn over? When you turn the key can you hear the fuel pumps turn on? Currently I am having similar issues with my car. The problem was due to a dying (cheap) fuel pump that was burning out the fuel pump relay. Sometimes the relay would work on start up, sometimes it wouldnt at all. Can you hear the relay clicking when you turn the ignition?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful thoughts. No, I haven't checked the relay or the fuel pump (noise). The car just turnes over. The fault always appears when trying to start in the morning. I dismissed cold start related items because when it eventually starts it runs perfect. I'll catch up with pump and relay! Thanks